# Matching across groups on R to control the influence of confounders

Tags: r, regression, matching, confounding, case-cohort

I have a cohort of individuals whose exact glucose measurements I have. I want to look at the influence of a variable (which I can call Var1) on the variation of glucose in this group. However, i don't want age, weight etc (confounders) to influence this and i would like to have a group of individuals who are matched for these confounders. i have a large cohort from which i am taking a certain amount from(equal amounts of people with low, normal, and high glucose levels so my group isn't composed mostly of people with high glucose or low glucose etc). So for instance for a person who has a glucose level considered low (within the low range) and who is in a certain age group, I would want there to be one person in the normal and in the high glucose range of a similar age group as well and so on with all the relevant confounders. At the end, I hope to have a cohort of individuals with varying levels of glucose (not categorized...just as it is) but who have their confounders matched and so I can properly measure the influence of Var1 on glucose variability.

Any advice on R packages and methods to perform this? I already did a linear regression to identify variables that influence glucose significantly to know what my confounders i need to match are. Any advice on my methods would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing doesn't really make sense. To reduce the confounding effects of a variable, you need to find units within each *treatment* group (i.e., each level of Var1) that have similar values of the variables (other than glucose). The outcome (glucose) should have no role in this part of the analysis. It should only be used in the final step of estimating the effect of Var1 on glucose in the matched sample. It is also not a good idea to sample based on the outcome; rather, you should sample based on the target population you are interested in (e.g., people with a certain age or weight distribution) or randomly for your pool of patients. Or, if possible, not sample at all and just use everyone you have data for.

Using regression to figure out which variables to adjust for is also not a great strategy. You should ensure balance (i.e., similarity of the distributions of variables) between the groups of Var1 on variables that might be related to glucose, prioritizing variables strongly related to glucose. If you don't know which variables are strongly related to glucose, you can use a separate sample to figure this out.

To perform matching in R, I recommend the [`MatchIt`](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/) package (of which I am an author). I have written extensive documentation for it explaining the various [methods of matching](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/matching-methods.html) available, best practices in [assessing balance](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/assessing-balance.html), and appropriate ways to [estimate the effect](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html) and its standard error. There are also the `Matching` and `optmatch` packages for more specialized forms of matching, though the functionality of these packages is contained within `MatchIt` as well.